# Datastore API Filter by field then sort ascending

Tags: sql, json, google-api, google-cloud-datastore

I'm playing around with the Google Datastore API ([runQuery](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/datastore.projects.runquery/m/datastore/v1/datastore.projects.runQuery) method), and I am trying to run the gQuery String

```
'Select * from Transaction Where User = "[Me]" ORDER BY Start[date] ASC'
```

Sending that JSON Object gives me the following error:

```html
400
 
- Show headers -
  
{
 "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "no matching index found. recommended index is:\n- kind: Transaction\n  properties:\n  - name: User\n  - name: Start\n",
  "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
 }
}
```

Alternatively, If I run this string:

```
 {
  "gqlQuery":
 {
  "allowLiterals":
  "queryString":"
     SELECT * FROM Transaction WHERE User = "[Me]"
    "

    }

  }
```

I get a 200 Response

```html
200
 
- Show headers -
  
{
 "batch": {
  "entityResultType": "FULL",
  "entityResults": [
   {
    "entity": {
     "key": {
      "partitionId": {
       "projectId": "project-id-5200999099906492774"
      },
      "path": [
       {
        "kind": "Transaction",
        "id": "4693202737039992"
       }
      ]
     },....
```

or if I run this one to just order all the results:

```
'Select * from Transaction ORDER BY Start[date] ASC'
```

I get a 200 Response as well:

```html
200
 
- Show headers -
  
{
 "batch": {
  "entityResultType": "FULL",
  "entityResults": [
   {
    "entity": {
     "key": {
      "partitionId": {
       "projectId": "project-id-5200707080506492774"
      },
      "path": [
       {
        "kind": "Transaction",
        "id": "5641081148407808"
       }
      ]
     },...
```

So how can I do both operations in one line?

**UPDATE:**

As recommended below, I have used the google cloud platform to update the indexes manually. You create a valid yaml file in notepad and then use the upload tool (three vertical dots button on the right side of the cloud control command line tool) to place it on the server and direct to it with the comand line. Here are my results so far:

```
nathaniel@project-id-5200707080555492774:~$ gcloud datastore create-indexes /home/nathaniel/index.yaml                                                                       

Configurations to update:
descriptor:      [/home/nathaniel/index.yaml]
type:            [datastore indexes]
target project:  [project-id-5200707044406492774]
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y
nathaniel@project-id-5200707080506492774:~$
```

This is the Yaml file I used:

```
indexes:
- kind: Transaction
  properties:
  - name: User
    direction: asc
  - name: Period
    direction: asc
  - name: Status
    direction: asc
  - name: auditStatus
    direction: asc
  - name: role
    direction: asc
  - name: Start
    direction: desc
  - name: End
    direction: asc
```

Still unable to complete the query, but it may take time to populate. I'll check back through the day and update my results. As of 1:35PM EST, The indexes still don't seem to have updated, as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error message says - in order to run the query with a `WHERE` and `ORDER`, you need a composite index on `User` and `Start` properties for `Transaction` kind. You can learn more about the indexes at https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes.

You can create indexes using the gcloud command line tool. Refer to the documentation at - https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore/create-indexes

Once your index is created/active, which may take a while depending on the amount of data you have, you should be able to run the first query.

Comment: Thank you Sai, that makes sense. I've followed the documentation to create an index.yaml file, and tried running the following command in the project's console: gcloud datastore create-indexes c\:index.yaml (The yaml file is sitting in my c drive right now). I get the error message "ERROR: (gcloud.datastore.create-indexes) Invalid value for [index_file]: You must provide the path to a valid index.yaml file." Could I get further clarification on how to update the index file on a project like this?

Comment: @NathanielMacIver - I see a typo in the file path, make sure it is `C:\index.yaml` and try again. (colon first, then the backslash, you have them swapped).

Comment: So After 24 hours, the Datastore installation does indicate there are 5,336 Composite Indices, but my original query still responds the same way. I logged my yaml file in the above post. Any Ideas?

Comment: @NathanielMacIver - if you are running the same query from your original post and getting the same exact error - I would recommend creating the index with the exact columns that were mentioned in the error message - recommended index is:- kind: Transaction\n  properties:\n  - name: User\n  - name: Start\n"